# How to represent a sequence as a constant-recursive sequence?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

A [constant-recursive sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence) is $$x_{i+m} = a_{m-1}x_{i+m-1} + a_{m-2}x_{i+m-2} + \cdots + a_0x_i,\tag{*} $$ where m is the order of sequence and $a_i$ is integer.
The sequence $\{2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 27, 16, 81, ...\}$ is a constant-recursive sequence. But I can't represent it in the form of $(*)$.

It can be noted that this sequence consists of two trivial subsequences $2x_{i}$ for $\{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...\}$ and $3x_{i}$ for $\{3, 9, 27, 81, 243, ...\}$.

The question is how the sequence $\{2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 27, 16, 81, ...\}$ can be represented as $( * )$. I would like to see general approaches for solving such problems (when there is an initial sequence consisting of two trivial subsequences).

Comment: Do you know how to write a closed form for $x_i$ in terms of the roots to $x^m-a_{m-1}x^{m-1}-\cdots-a_0?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know that $\{2, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, ...\}$ has the characteristic polynomial $$x^2-2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you know how the closed formula for $x_n$ corresponds to the roots of the polynomial:

$$p(x)=x^m-a_{m-1}x^{m-1}-\cdots-a_0$$

Assuming indices start at $i=0.$

The sequence $$y=(2,0,4,0,8,0,\dots)$$ can be written as:

$$y_i=\frac{(\sqrt 2)^{i+2}+(-\sqrt 2)^{i+2}}{2}$$

Similarly, $$z=(0,3,0,9,0,\dots)$$ can be written:

$$z_i=\frac{(\sqrt 3)^{i+1}+(-\sqrt 3)^{i+1}}{2}$$

So your sequence, $y+z,$ corresponds to the polynomial $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)=x^4-5x^2+6,$ which has roots $\pm \sqrt 2,\pm\sqrt 3.$

---

More generally, if $x_i$ is a recurrence corresponding to $p(x)$ and $y_i$ aecurrence correspondind to $q(x)$ then $$(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\dots)$$
corresponds to:
$$p(x^2)q(x^2)$$

(Sometimes you can find a smaller common recurrence, but this one always works.)

Your case is the particularly easy case, $p(x)=x-2, q(x)=x-3.$

The nature of $p(x^2)q(x^2)$ is to have no odd terms, so the corresponding recurrence is has even terms depend only on previous even terms, and odd terms only on previous odd terms.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Could you explain  to write a closed form for ${x_i}$ in terms of the roots to ${x^m} - {a_{m - 1}}{x^{m - 1}} - ... - {a_0}$.  I've only met this formula before: ${x_{n + 1}} = a{x_n} + b \Rightarrow {x^2} - (a + 1)x + a$ . And this was called the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: And how would it be possible to prove that the resulting sequence is $p\left( {{x^2}} \right)q\left( {{x^2}} \right)$?

Comment: If you don’t know that result, it is a bit much to cover in an answer here. That is why I mentioned the need to know it up front. @alexhak

Comment: But here’s a link. https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/